# Potential In VA

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current-mirror, differential-amplifier

[image]

I'm trying to find VA and I don't get something, is Ic1 = V+/20k, and then this current splits through emitters of Q1 and Q2? If so, then the voltage VA is 0?
Also, I know that Q3 and Q4 are a Darlington pair, but what is Q5 doing there?

Comment: \$V_A\$ is equal to \$V_A = V_+ -  I_{C2}R_{C2} \$  KVL in action. So where is the problem?

Comment: Elena, You try to blindly analyze something without understanding it; you have not even mention the name of the circuit. Is not it more correct to understand the circuit first, at least on a conceptual level, and only then to look for an answer to your specific question? First of all, you need to know the function of each element... why it is placed in the circuit... Then you need to know how to calculate its value...

Answer (score 2):

Q7, Q8 are a current mirror. Q9 is a Widlar current sink.

I1 (about 400uA) mirrored into Iq splits between Q1 and Q2 depending on the voltages at v1 and v2.

If v1 = v2  (with some additional limits on the common-mode voltage), and if the transistors are perfectly matched, it should split evenly.

Q5 is an emitter follower.

Comment: Thanks! But how about VA?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Well I keep thinking it might be 0

Comment: How are you calculating zero?

Comment: I forgot to mention that v1 and v2 are considered 0. Sorry, I calculated again, and now I have -0,7. I don't get if I calculated right IC1 as 10V/20k ..?

Comment: Ic1 ~= Ie1 which is not 10V/20K.